# xsl gets attributes with dollar as php variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

my xsl stylesheet just works fine except the thing that i cant use attributes in my stylesheet. But i really need them to complete my function.

I'm using the xsl in php and when i try to declare an attribute and use , the xsl thinks that $attr is a php variable and the function crashes.

This is my code

```
<?php
function releaseNotes($source, $type, $order_by, $sort) {

$type = $type ? "[@type='{$type}']" : "";

$xsl = <<<XSL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="versions" match="issue" use="fix_versions"/>
<xsl:key name="type" match="issue" use="concat(fix_versions, '+', @type)"/>

  <xsl:template match="issues">



      <xsl:for-each select="//issue[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('versions', fix_versions)[1])]">

        <xsl:sort select="fix_versions" order="descending"/> 

        <div class="release">

            <a href="" class="version"><xsl:value-of select="fix_versions"/></a>




            <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="fix_versions"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$version"/>
            <xsl:if test="//release[@version = '$version']">
              Yeah
            </xsl:if>



            <div class="version" style="display:none;">

            <xsl:for-each select="key('versions', fix_versions)">

                <xsl:for-each select="key('type', concat(fix_versions, '+', @type))">
                    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid grey;">
                    <a href="" class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a>
                    <div class="toggle" style="display:none;">
                        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>

                </div>
          </div>                        
            </xsl:for-each>

            </div>
       </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL;

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xmldoc->load($source);
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
return $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
}
?>
```

No matter where i try to use an attribute - as soon as i want to use it, i get no result of the function anymore? Any idea?

Seems to be useless in this example but i want to check if there is a node "release" with this version number so i need to get the version of the current string as an attribute.

The xml structure is like this

```
<release version="x.x.x" name="release1"/>
<release version="x.x.x" name="release2"/>
<release version="x.x.x" name="release3"/>
<issues>
  <issue><fix_versions>x.x.x</fix_versions></issue>
  <issue><fix_versions>x.x.x</fix_versions></issue>
  <issue><fix_versions>x.x.x</fix_versions></issue>
</issues>
```

Only issues of already released versions should be visible. Thats why i have to check for the issue if there is an release with the same version

Everything works fine, even grouping, but the attributes. As i said the function takes $version just as a php variable instead of the name of the aatribute.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your stylesheet does not reference $attr, so what is your problem? You want to insert an attribute - where and what value? Could you show us a sample input document and its expected output?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the first post. I thought it would be enough this way because it was a general problem :) I added an example and the xml structure

Comment: In your stylesheet $version does not refer to any thing. You have not defined any parameter or variable called version.

Comment: Also at the time of your test the focus node is the issue node, and yet you reference release which is not a child of issue. Perhaps you were trying to reference the output tree, which you cannot do in XSLT?

Comment: Also your listing beginning with "The xml structure is like this..", is this meant to be the input document? If so, it seems you have forgotten to list the expected output.

Comment: isnt that `<xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="fix_versions"/></xsl:attribute>` already the definition of $version? I'm using an CMS based on XML. There i just can do `<xsl:attribute name="version">value</xsl:attribute>` and call it via  `<xsl:value-of select="$version">` - Thats all.

Comment: And sorry, but is a output really important for you? I can add the expected output, but i thought this is not important because it's only the attributes/parameters that dont work

Comment: shouldnt something like this `<xsl:attribute name="bla">ba</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="$bla"/>` work? Shouldnt it work, no matter in which node I am, because i instantyl call the attribute right after declaring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but if you mean the problem is that:

```
$type = $type ? "[@type='{$type}']" : "";
```

gets translated as $type is a variable and gets expanded, if you put a \ in front of the variable, it will work, or even in single quotes:

```
$type = $type ? "[@type='{\$type}']" : "";
or 
$type = $type ? "[@type='".'{$type}'."']" : "";
```

Comment: Oh guys, i found my mistake and im really sorry for wasting your time. What i wanted was to create a variable - not an attribute. It was late and i read attribute anywhere and from there variable was replaced by attribute in my head. I'm really sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: No problem. Sometimes you just have to say what the problem is to see the answer yourself.